# Can anyone explain to me what this preg_match() function does?

Tags: php, function, methods

So I'm reading this book on object oriented programming in PHP, and in an example method where the author is checking data type I came across this function:

```
//class AddressManager...
function outputAddresses( $resolve ) {
  if ( is_string( $resolve ) ) {
    $resolve =
      ( preg_match("/false|no|off/i", $resolve ) )?
      false:true;
  }
  // ...
}
```

can anyone tell me what its purpose is? The properties don't matter but it's a method designed to convert a string into a boolean (I think).

Answer (score 2):

`preg_match` in itself does not convert a string to a boolean, it is a regular expression matching function.  What you have there is a ternary expression which pretty much evaluates to this:

```
class AddressManager
... 
    function outputAddresses( $resolve ) 
    { 
    if ( is_string( $resolve ) ) 
    { 
      if (preg_match("/false|no|off/i", $resolve))
      {
         $resolve = false;
      } else {
         $resolve = true;
      }
      // $resolve = ( preg_match("/false|no|off/i", $resolve ) )? false:true; 
    } 
// ... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the variable $resolve contains "false" or "no" or "off" in an insensitive way (disregards case), then return FALSE.  Otherwise return TRUE.

Looks like a simple user input checker (and not a very good one at that).  What happens, for example, if you enter "nothing" or "now" ?

Comment: good point you have there, but the property $resolve is taken from an xml settings file using the simpleXML API, so i guess the property is already predetermined and does not need that much error catching, thanks for replying so quickly though! lots of replies in the time it takes to go to the shower, I like this site a lot!

Answer (score 0):

PseudoCode for the above.

```
if( $resolve equals false  or no or off)
then 
    set  $resolve as false
else
    set  $resolve as true
```

The ? (ternary operator) simply replaces the above lines of code. This is what happens behind the scenes.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation